# Nodejs - many REST calls from the node server will impact the overall performance?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

If I had a nodeJS as a backend for my application.
And lets say 10000 clients will call the backend to a simple function:

```
func {

 // Call to a rest web-service of a far away 3rd party server (different 3rd party service each call)

}
```

Will this cause any performance hit on the system? I mean , nodeJS is a single threaded process. so this question is required.

Again - Pay attention that the REST call is from the server not the clients browsers. (obviously from clients browser the impact is eliminated)

Comment: No, and this is _because_ node is single threaded.

Comment: Do all clients do **exactly the same** request to a 3rd party REST service? Then you should cache the data and make this request only once.

Comment: user2415266 - No, each call is for a different service

Comment: Benjamin Gruenbaum - Can you please elaborate? or maybe give a reference

Answer (score 0):

> Will this cause any performance hit on the system?

Yes, of course. Making any number of http requests will cause a 'performance hit'... I suggest you look into possible limitations which will likely cause these requests to *not* execute in parallel. And do some benchmarks with real code to see if you have a problem.

Comment: I was asking if the impact will be more then the regular impact if you would have done it on a multithreaded backend.

Comment: Depends on the technique used in the other case... Node does not hold on to a thread for each request, so it's better, performance-wise than a blocking implementation. Node, however is just one of many ways to achieve this 'asynchronous' behaviour.